# How to parse HTML correctly with DOMDocument?

Tags: php, html, dom

Lets say I have this type of HTML website:

```
stuff
<div id="123">
*HTML CODE I NEED*
</div>
stuff
<div id="234">
*HTML CODE I NEED*
</div>
more stuff
```

How can I extract *HTML CODE I NEED* from those div's, given that I know their IDs ? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the nodes with [`DOMDocument::getElementById` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php) and the text content with the [`textContent` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.textcontent) property.

If you want the inner HTML of the nodes, you can call [`DOMDocument::saveHTML` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php).